# Can one use conditions and loops on a single line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would one go about turning the following code into the latter?

```
<div id="faqs">
  <% if @faqs.length > 0 %>
    <% @faqs.each do |faq| %>
      <div class="faq">
        <strong>Q:</strong> <%= faq.question %>
        <br />
        <strong>A:</strong> <%= faq.answer %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <p>No FAQs to display.</p>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div id="faqs">
  <% @faqs.empty? ? content_tag(:p, "No FAQs to display.") : @faqs.each do |faq| %>
    <div class="faq">
      <strong>Q:</strong> <%= faq.question %>
      <br />
      <strong>A:</strong> <%= faq.answer %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm curious as to whether I can get the latter code to work. The only element of it that is failing at the moment is that the `content_tag()` is not displaying - this is due to the fact that I'm not using printable ruby tags (`<%= # %>`) but using them will dump out the FAQ objects underneath the content.

I considered the use of `puts()` to print the `content_tag()` while inside the ruby tags but that didn't work.

I've tried to search for this issue but haven't yielded anything useful.

Is this achievable and if so, does it have any benefits other than being prettier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to make the later code to work if you can put the body of the loop in a helper function and return the out put of `content_tag` from that. The line in view file might be somewhat like this.

```
<%= @faqs.empty? ? content_tag(:p, "No FAQs to display.") : printList(@faqs) %>
```

and your `printList` function will return the output of nested `content_tag`s. You can make a generic list printing function which can be used for any list.

Something so obvious but still shared.

Answer (score 3):

This should work (for clarity, I moved FAQ tag generation in separate helper method):

```
<div id="faqs">
  <%= raw (@faqs.empty? ? content_tag(:p, "No FAQs to display.") : @faqs.map { |faq| faq_div(faq) }.join) %>
</div>
```

or, perhaps more clean:

```
<div id="faqs">
  <%= content_tag(:p, "No FAQs to display.") if @faqs.empty? %>
  <%= raw @faqs.map { |faq| faq_div(faq) }.join %>
</div>
```

meanwhile, in helpers:

```
def faq_div(faq)
  '<div class="faq"><strong>Q:</strong> %s<br /><strong>A:</strong> %s</div>' % [faq.question, faq.answer]
end
```

Comment: Tested with success - thanks for proposing a clean and useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<% if @faqs.each do |faq| %>
  <div class="faq">
    <strong>Q:</strong> <%= faq.question %>
    <br />
    <strong>A:</strong> <%= faq.answer %>
  </div>
<% end.empty? %>
  <p>No FAQs to display.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: -1 while it works, this is quite an ugly code. reading return values from `each` loop? puh-leez.